# Is there special term for class of words which are irregular in forming their plural form?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-number

There are such words as ox - oxen, torus - tori and many other which are irregular in a way of forming their plural form and I'm wondering if there is a special term for such words? On a side note I will appreciate some link which lists all these words to get an idea of total number of those.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on English plurals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals) is excellent, even giving subsets of _irregular plurals_ and advice on usages.

Comment: So I guess those are called just "irregular plurals" and there is no fancy/obscure term for them? :) I don't know why I'm expected one :)

Comment: 'Words with irregular plurals' is all I'm aware of. ('Irregular' refers to the fact that they don't add the usual 's' or 'es' rather than how they look. So 'sheep' has an irregular plural, 'sheep'.) Some words have two or three plural forms.

Comment: The normal term is nouns with irregular plural (not: words with irregular plural). And that should be sufficient. Why another special grammar term?  We have already far too many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently they are called "irregular nouns."  K12Reader.com [refers](http://www.k12reader.com/term/irregular-plural-nouns/)  to them this way.  So does [English Language Terminology](http://www.englishlanguageterminology.org/parts-of-speech/irregular-nouns.htm).  If you google "irregular noun," you should find many pages about them.  That should confirm that the terminology is common enough.